# Using stored procedure to pull data from database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I using two stored procedure to pull data from a database. When I use this stored procedure

```
select distinct a.Req_No,a.Req_Date,a.employee_id,a.department,
a.employee_name, 
b.item_no, b.expense_acc, c.ACTDESCR+'/'+c.ACTNUMBR_1+'-'+c.ACTNUMBR_2 [Expense_Acc], b.unit_of_measure,b.quantity_requested,b.description 
from Requisition a inner join Requisitionitem b
Inner Join [TWCL].dbo.GL00100 c
    on b.expense_acc = c.ACTINDX 
on a.Req_No =b.Req_No where status=-1
```

It returns all items on the requisition number that has a status of -1

However when I use this sp instead it returns only the requisition number that has a status of -1 which I understand why

```
SELECT distinct a.Req_No,Req_Date
FROM [dbo].[RequisitionItem] a Inner Join [dbo].[Requisition] b
ON a.Req_No = b.Req_No
Inner Join [TWCL].dbo.GL00100 c
ON a.expense_acc = c.ACTINDX
Inner Join  [TWCL].dbo.GL00100 d
On d.ACTINDX = a.expense_acc
Inner Join [TWCL].dbo.IV00101 e
on a.item_no = e.ITEMNMBR
WHERE b.status = -1
```

In combination with this stored procedure

```
    SELECT a.ITEMNMBR, a.ITEMDESC, ab.employee_id, ab.department,ab.employee_name,quantity_requested,b.expense_acc, c.ACTDESCR+'/'+c.ACTNUMBR_1+'-'+c.ACTNUMBR_2 [Expense_Acc],
     b.unit_of_measure
FROM [TWCL].[dbo].IV00101 a inner Join RequisitionItem b on a.ITEMNMBR = b.item_no
Inner Join Requisition ab
    on ab.Req_No = b.Req_No
Inner Join [TWCL].dbo.GL00100 c
    on b.expense_acc = c.ACTINDX 
where b.Req_No = @Req_No
```

On the webpage the data is duplicated with the first stored procedure but it is not with the second. So the second SP returns the correct data.

When I'm using this controller; postobj with the first SP returning a count 4 if it is 5 items and the second returns a count of 2(which is correct)

```
  public ActionResult RequisitionList(List<Requisition> postingObj)
    {

        IssueDAO dbObj = new IssueDAO(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        //TransactionIssues transissues = new TransactionIssues();
        //transissues.docNumber = string.Concat("IS", DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmddhhmmss"));
        List<string> reqNumbers = new List<string>();



        foreach (var item in postingObj)
        {
            if (item.postTrnx)
            {
                reqNumbers.Add(item.reqNumber);
            }
        }
        if (reqNumbers.Count == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Please select at least one requested item";
            return View(dbObj.GetAllRequest());
        }

        dbObj.SetRequisitionStatus0(reqNumbers);
        ViewBag.Message = "Approval Successful!";
        return View(dbObj.GetAllRequest());
    }
```

My question is why does the first one returns a count of 4 when there is 5 items as well as I'm using a checkbox so the user can select an item and approve it but I select one item it throws the error message Please select at least one requested item" because reqNumbers is getting a count of zero.

Model

```
 public List<Requisition> GetAllRequest()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("getallrequests", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                List<Requisition> request = new List<Requisition>();

                SqlDataReader rdrObj;

                connection.Open();
                rdrObj = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdrObj.Read())
                {
                    Requisition requisition = new Requisition();


                    requisition.reqNumber = rdrObj.GetString(0);
                    requisition.reqDate = rdrObj.GetDateTime(1);

                    requisition.items = getRequestItemByRquisition(rdrObj.GetString(0));
                    request.Add(requisition);
                }
                rdrObj.Close();


                return request;
            }
        }
    }

 public List<Item> getRequestItemByRquisition(string Req_No)
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        SqlConnection TWCLOPConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());
        SqlCommand itemscommand = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader itemRdr;
        itemscommand.CommandText = "requisition_sp_getItemNum ";
        itemscommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        itemscommand.Connection = TWCLOPConnect;
        itemscommand.Parameters.Add("@Req_No", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Req_No;

        try
        {
            TWCLOPConnect.Open();
            itemRdr = itemscommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (itemRdr.Read())
            {


                Item item = new Item();
                //Requisition requisition = new Requisition();
                item.itemNumber = itemRdr.GetString(0);
                item.description = itemRdr.GetString(1);
                ////item.price = Convert.ToDouble(itemRdr[3]);
                item.employeeDetails.employeeNum = Convert.ToInt32(itemRdr.GetString(2));
                item.employeeDetails.department = itemRdr.GetString(3);
                item.employeeDetails.LoggedInUserName = itemRdr.GetString(4);
                item.quantity = Convert.ToDouble(itemRdr[5]);
                item.expense_account.index = itemRdr.GetInt32(6);
                item.expense_account.account_desc = itemRdr.GetString(7);
                ////item.lineNum = itemRdr.GetInt32(7);
               item.selecteduomtext = itemRdr.GetString(8);

                items.Add(item);
            }
            itemRdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            TWCLOPConnect.Close();
        }

        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Slight detour...https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: Without more details nobody can answer this. We can't see your tables and have no idea what your data is like.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT will eliminate those rows where all the selected fields are identical.

- In the first stored procedure, you have referenced 11 columns.
- In the second stored procedure, you have referenced only two columns.

Try to add same columns in second stored procedure you will get same result as first stored procedure.

Comment: Yeah I did that but in combination with this requisition_sp_getItemNum the data is duplicating

Comment: requisition.items = getRequestItemByRquisition(rdrObj.GetString(0)); this is the part that gets the items based on req_no; I've tried commenting that section out but no items would show on the web page